# Conditional probability of joint events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y, Z$ be three random variables. Is the equality
$$
P(X=x, Y=y |Z=z) = P(X=x|Y=y,Z=z) P(Y=y|Z=z)
$$
true?
Note that $P(X,Y)$ denotes the joint probability of random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I haven't seen the $A,B$ notation. What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. It P(X,Y) is the joint probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality holds true given $P(Z=z)>0$ and $P(Y=y,Z=z)>0$. This immediately follows from the definition of the conditional probability: If $A, \ B$ are events, such that $P(B)>0,$ then $P(A|B)=P(A,B)/P(B)$. So we have $$ \frac{P(X=x,Y=y|Z=z)}{P(Y=y|Z=z)} = \frac{P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)}{P(Z=z)}\frac{P(Z=z)}{P(Y=y,Z=z)} = \frac{P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)}{P(Y=y,Z=z)} = P(X=x|Y=y,Z=z).$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I revised the question and hopefully is it now clear. By $P(X)$, I just meant $P(X=x)$ which is the event of random variable $X$ being equal to $x$.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Just replace the event $X$ in my answer by $\{X=x\}$ and same for $Z$ and $Y$.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I revised the answer using the new notation.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you meant joint *densities*, in which case it is true.

In general you represent it by f and we have

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)$$

You can condition on any number of other random variables

$$f_{X,Y|W,Z}(x,y|w,z)=f_{X|Y,W,Z}(x|y,w,z)f_{Y|w,z}(y|w,z)$$

and still be "true."